# Tensorflow ValueError:cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type float32_ref, when trying to load a model saved as .pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, batch-normalization

I have a trained tensorflow model saved in form of a checkpoint, .data, .meta, and a .index file. The model uses batch normalization.
I tried converting it to .pb file using [freeze_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py), which can be imported as `from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph`. The input to this is also a `.pb` file but one which has only the graph structure. 
I restore the model with the following code

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'.\path\to\model\VanillaCNN.0000.meta') 
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(r'.\path\to\model'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

Then a `.pb` file which contains the graph structure is created with

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, "", "model_proto.pb", False)
```

After this the I use `freeze_graph` to generate a `.pb` file which includes the graph structure as well as the weights.
The inputs to `freeze_graph` were

```
input_graph_path = r'.\path\to\model\model_proto.pb'
input_saver_def_path = ""
input_binary = False
input_checkpoint_path = r'.\path\to\model\VanillaCNN.0000'
output_node_names = "VanillaCNNoutput_10/layer_output"
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_graph_path = r'.\path\to\model\frozen_model.pb'
clear_devices = False
initializer_nodes=""
```

executed as

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,input_binary, input_checkpoint_path,output_node_names, restore_op_name,filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,clear_devices,initializer_nodes)
```

This creates `frozen_model.pb`, when I try to load it back as below

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map=None, return_elements=None, name="", op_dict=None, producer_op_list=None)
    return graph
```

it throws the following error

```
ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node 'VanillaCNNconv_0/VanillaCNNconv_0/cond/Assign': Input tensor 'VanillaCNNconv_0/VanillaCNNconv_0/cond/Assign/Switch:1' Cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type float32_ref.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks similar to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3628, and unfortunately I don't have a great solution for this yet, partly because I haven't been able to create a simple reproducible test case. There are some suggestions in the conversation that may help though.

Comment: @PeteWarden I'm trying to convert the model to `.pb` in order to make the model part of an android app, is there an alternative approach, which doesn't require the `.pb` file.